# Microsoft Sync framework, sync database with files

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I want to sync a database who represent my file and a local folder who contain files.

I have seen the FileSyncProdivder and the SQLSyncProvider but i want to know if I need te create a custom provider or if someone have alreay did this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two (FileSyncProvider and SQLSyncProvider)providers will not sync with each other.you will have to write your own code to do this.

Comment: And can i need to write both or i write just one and i take the FileSyncProvider ?

Comment: you can write one to make sure it matches the destination provider. not an easy task if i may say so. files and database tables being completely different.